# AJAX not accepting data with space

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this AJAX script that passes data from DataTable to a PHP page, and then being outputted to a modal. It can pass data if its just a whole world, like **FINANCE/STOCK**, **DISBURSEMENT**, etc, but if the data is like **FINANCE 1**, **FINANCE 2**, etc. It shows `null`.

This line is from my DataTable

```
{
                    "targets": 6,
                    "data": "approvedby",
                    "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        var table = '&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm preview btn-flat" data-id=' + row['department'] + ':' + row['jobposition'] + '><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Preview</button>';
                        table += ((data == null) ? '&nbsp<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm edit btn-flat" data-id=' + row['department'] + ':' + row['jobposition'] +  '><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Edit</button>' : '');
                        table += ((data == null) ? '&nbsp<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm approve btn-flat" data-id=' + row['department'] + ':' + row['jobposition'] +  '><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Approve</button>' : '');
                        return table += ((data == null) ? '&nbsp<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete btn-flat" data-id=' + row['department'] + ':' + row['jobposition'] +  '><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Delete</button>' : '');
                    }
                }
```

I tried to output the code so that I can see if it really accepts the data, and it does.

```
var table = '&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm preview btn-flat" data-id=' + row['department'] + ':' + row['jobposition'] + '><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> ' + row['department'] + ':' + row['jobposition'] + ' Preview</button>';
```

This picture is from my DataTable. As you can see, I can clearly verify that the data is being accepted properly from dataTable.

[image]

Now, the problem is, when I'm passing this data via AJAX, it does not accept the data because it has a space.

```
<script>
$("body").on('click', '.preview', function (e){ // standard view
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'human_resource_jobpositionentry_masterfile_data_row.php',
            data: {referenceno:id}
        }).done(function(d){
            console.log('d: '+d);
            $('#jobpositionentry_masterfile_modal_loader').html(d);
            $('#jobpositionentry_masterfile_modal_loader').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is showing `null`, this is from my modal.

[image]

This the part of the modal where it is being displayed.

```
    <div class='form-group'>
                            <label for='add_idno' class='col-sm-3 control-label'>Series No.</label>
                            <div class='col-sm-9'>
                                <div id="jobpositionentry_masterfile_modal_loader">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

This data is being exploded here.

```
<?php 
    include 'backend/conn.php';
    //include 'backend/session.php';
    if(isset($_POST['referenceno'])){
        $id = $_POST['referenceno'];

        $forexplode=explode(':',$id);
        echo    $departmentexplode = $forexplode[0];
        echo    $jobpositionexplode = $forexplode[1];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM hrdjobpositionentry WHERE department LIKE '%$departmentexplode%' AND jobposition LIKE '%$jobpositionexplode%'";
        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo json_encode($row);
    }
?>
```

> May I ask for the reason as to why AJAX does not pass a data with a space?

Comment: you are passing your data here  data: {referenceno:id} Right???

Comment: @PrakashKarena yes, via ````data: {referenceno:id}````, and it's from ````var id = $(this).data('id');````

Comment: you are getting your id in  {referenceno:id} before passing to ajax request?? please check...

Comment: @PrakashKarena, yes, it's being captured properly..

Comment: So, problem is you are not getting  $id = $_POST['referenceno']; here Right?

Comment: @PrakashKarena yes, correct. When the data have a space, the space is being replaced as null. example: ````ACCOUNTINGFINANCEnull````

Comment: @James this is my data-id ````data-id=' + row['department'] + ':' + row['jobposition'] + '````, and the data that is supposed to be passed is **ACCOUNTING:FINANCE 1**

Comment: we are steel confused you are passing    var id = $(this).data('id'); as id = ACCOUNTING:FINANCE 1 full string or just number?

Comment: @PrakashKarena it was a merged data, then I will just explode it because it does not have a reference no, this is a legacy database that i'm working on.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef ill check that one..

Comment: You simply neglected to properly put the attribute value into quotes. `data-id=' + row['department'] + ':' + row['jobposition'] + '` will result in something like `data-id=foo bar`, so of course the value of the attribute is only `foo` in this case. (The single quotes here are the JavaScript string delimiters, they are not attribute value delimiters.)

Comment: @04FS may I ask on how can I properly write this? I tried double quoting it, but I'm still having the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass data like below

```js
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'human_resource_jobpositionentry_masterfile_data_row.php',
            data: JSON.stringify({referenceno:id}) //change 
        })
```

Might be you are not getting your id in back-end side in JSON formate.
Hope this will help you **If you have any problem then let me know.**

Comment: what you are passing in id from front end ? string or number

Comment: It's a data from my datatable, so it's a string.

Comment: I did a dirty workaround for now.. I replaced the strings. ````$strjobpositionexplode = $jobpositionexplode;
$newstrjobpositionexplode = str_replace ( "%20"," ", $strjobpositionexplode );````

Comment: great keep it up.